# laravel join tables column not found

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent

Hi I am building an application and I have a table for example projects and then settings. However they do not have a foreign key with each other and i have other tables such as tasks, clients etc. And these have settings which I am planning to save in the settings table.

The settings table has a column of type, which i will fill with the related model name e.g. `project`. Anyway when i am fetching a project I also want to fetch a the settings where the type = project. So I've tried to do a table join instead however this has thrown the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'project' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `projects` inner join `settings` on `type` = `project`)
```

The code I've used is as follows:

```
return \Project::()->join('settings', 'type', '=', 'project')->get();
```

I see what the problem is, its looking for a column called project however there isn't one. I suppose what i want to do is use eloquent and a query function to join the table and then query the settings table where type = project. does anyone know how i can do this?

### update from burak answer

I've tried to put this in my model as so so

settings.php

```
public function sprint() { 
return \Setting::where('type', '=', 'sprint')->get(); 
}
```

and sprint.php

```
public function settings() {
 return \Setting::where('type', '=', 'sprint')->get(); 
}
```

however I get this error Call to undefined method

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints() and I've called it using this method:

```
return Sprint::with(['settings'])->get();
```

what have i done wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are not referencing the table names and you are comparing columns. Instead, what you need is a `where` statement within your join condition to compare with a value.

```
return DB::table('projects')
    ->join('settings', function ($join) {
        $join->where('settings.type', '=', 'project');
    })->get();
```

But you should better get settings and projects one by one as all identical settings columns will be added to your projects rows which is not good.

```
$data = [];
$data['projects'] = Project::all();
$data['settings'] = Settings::where('type', '=', 'project')->first();
return $data;
```

**Update:**

Within your Sprint model

```
public function scopeWithType()
{
    return static::join('settings', function ($join) {
        $join->where('settings.type', '=', 'sprint');
    });
}
```

Then within the controller

```
Sprint::withType()->get();
```

Comment: ahh cool thanks I've tried to put this in my model as so so settings.php   public function sprint() {
        return \Setting::where('type', '=', 'sprint')->get();
    }
 and sprint.php     public function settings()
    {
        return \Setting::where('type', '=', 'sprint')->get();
    } however  I get this error  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::addEagerConstraints()
 and I've called it using this method: return Sprint::with(['settings'])->get(); what have i done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried but I think this is what you want. This is how we do subqueries or query joins with where clause.

```
return \Project::join('settings', function($q) {
    $q->where('type', '=', 'project');
})->get();
```

your code looks for records matching `project` field in the table `settings` and `type` field in the `project` table, which is not the case.

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: remove `->get()` from the return statement to get rid of the error. Put this after when you have called `sprint()` or `settings()` to get rid of the error. Let me edit my answer in a moment.